# Inserting Appendices after Bibliography

Tags: thesis

Hi I am using the Sunil Patel thesis template for my thesis. This is dependent on a thesis.cls file that is [here](https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/Thesis.cls). The problem is that my college requires the Appendices to be after the Bibliography and I am unable to work out how to modify the .cls file to achieve this.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. To clarify, do you mean this template? http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis From that template, there is no need to modify the class file, the position of bibliography/appendix is defined by where they are placed in the code, so you simply need to move the appendix stuff to after the bibliography stuff.

Comment: First, do not modify the CLS. Second, ask your tutor if you have understood him correctly. Thirdly, read Thesis.pdf and check where the bibliography is placed. Are you familiar with the basics of TeXing, do you have the support of a colleague? Thesis Todo List.rtf is no work order or requirement for LaTeX

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks that is the template yes. I have tried just putting the appendix stuff after the bibliography stuff but what then happens is that I don't get "Bibliography" included in the table of contents. Might this be something to do with the \backmatter command?

Comment: Try putting `\backmatter` before the bibliography stuff.

Answer (score 2):

In order to complete the request of the OP, adding `\backmatter` as user TorbjørnT suggested is not enough because the appendix headers would remain hidden. To have it correctly set put:

1. `\backmatter` between the chapter section and bibliography section in main.tex.
2. `\mainmatter` between the bibliography section and appendix section in main.tex.

Assuming that the appendix stuff was already pasted after the bibliography.